# Winrt How to make a specific item to be first in listview?

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have an `ObservableCollection` of Users. This collection holds all the users and one user which is the owner.

My object holds:
Users.
Owner (which is also user).

I want to make the owner to be the first item in the listview.
How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
lvUsers.ItemsSource = UsersCollection; //Here I should do a linq I think.

<ListView x:Name="lvUsers">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BirthDate}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either use a `CollectionView`, or just sort the original `IEnumerable` before filling the ObservableCollection.

Comment: I can't use CollectionView because winrt doesn't supports it for my needs. And about the sort, how can I sort that?

Comment: sort the items `before` putting them into the observablecollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListView` etc. only distract from the actual question: how do I sort objects by type? If you want the owner on top, this is what you can do:

```
var orderedList = users.OrderByDescending(u => u is Owner)
                       .ThenBy(u => u.Name); // For instance
```

The first ordering is descending because `false` comes before `true`.

You can build the `ObservableCollection` from `orderedList`.